# Having Errors displaying which tv character the user compares to after answering select menu

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, arrayobject

```
  function onSelectMenuBlur() {
    "use strict";
    var sm = document.getElementById("selectmenu");
```

characters is 2D array

```
var characters = [[], [], [], [], []];
```

onchange that determines what is the selected index from the select menu in html code.  Adds value of 1 to index in 2D array of characters above

```
    sm.onchange = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
    if (i === this.selectedIndex) {
        characters[i].push(1);
        alert(characters[i].length);
    } else {
        characters[i].pop();
    }
}
    };
```

function pushA adds a value to the characters array that I can pull later to see which array is longest.

```
    function pushA() {
    for(var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
        if(characters[i].value === 1){
            characters[i].array.push(1);

        }
        else{}
    }
    }
    pushA();
```

Below is an object of characters the user is compared to depending on their selected index above

```
 characters = [
    {name: "rick",
    array: []

    },
    {name: "shane",
    array: []
    },
    {name: "carol",
    array: []
    },
    {
    name: "glen",
    array: []   
    },
    {
    name: "daryl",  
    array: []
    }
    ];
```

longestObjects function finds the longest array or arrays in object of arrays called characters above

```
    function longestObjects(characters) {
    var longest = 0;
    var longestO = [];
    characters.forEach(function(character) {
        if(character.array.length > longest){
        longestO = [character];
        longest = character.array.length;   
        }
        else if(character.array.length === longest) {
            longestO.push(character);
        }
        });


}
```

when the user clicks off the selectmenu, the longest array of characters alerts

```
sm.onblur = function() {
longestObjects();
};
//the onchange works but not the onblur!!!      
}
```

Comment: @Barmar  I think error is in Foreach?

Comment: `longestObjects` is defined as taking a `characters` argument but you when call it, you provide no argument.